# Keep getting a "Cannot find name 'subscribe'" error when trying to subscribe to data from http link (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have been trying to learn angular and have been watching a tutorial series. This episode is trying to teach how to get data from GitHub users, to create a user list on the webpage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w755PKU5DZg&list=PLseEp7p6EwiajxL9R4_o2dF7q3LxLWPFb&index=13).

I have looked everywhere but can't find a single thing I have done differently from the tutorial. Does anyone know why I am getting these errors? ("Cannot find name 'subscribe'" "Declaration or statement expected" and "parameter data implicitly has an 'any' type"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '
    <!-- header -->
    <app-header></app-header>
   
    <!-- routes get injected here-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <!-- footer -->
    <app-footer></app-footer>


 ',
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=10');
      .subscribe(data => { //this is the line that is giving me the errors.
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's a clue: if you comment out the line before the error message won't change.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon incorrectly placed on this line:

```
this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=10');
```